# Error when importing PyMC

Tags: python, anaconda, pymc

I have just installed PyMC on my mac (10.9.4) using anaconda (Anaconda 2.0.1) and the following command I copied from the pymc distribution page:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/pymc pymc
```

Everything seemed to be alright during the installation (no error messages, all the fetching completed). Then when I imported it I got the following error messages:

```
>>> import pymc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .CommonDeterministics import *
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/CommonDeterministics.py", line 21 in <module>
    from .utils import safe_len, stukel_logit, stukel_invlogit, logit, invlogit, value, find_element
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/utils.py", line 14, in <module>
from . import flib
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/flib.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/flib.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I am new to python and I don't really know what to do next to not mess up. I typed this to find other packages:

```
 binstar search -t conda pymc

 Packages:
                      Name | Access       | Package Types   | Summary             
 ------------------------- | ------------ | --------------- | --------------------
             asmeurer/pymc | public       | conda           | https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc
                auto/pymcu | published    | conda           | http://www.pymcu.com
             bkreider/pymc | public       | conda           | https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc
      datamicroscopes/pymc | public       | conda           | None                
           fonnesbeck/pymc | public       | conda           | https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc
             jonsedar/pymc | public       | conda           | None                
                 pymc/pymc | public       | conda           | None                
             rsignell/pymc | public       | conda           | Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampling toolkit.
          tobeplugged/pymc | public       | conda           | None                
           tomku-test/pymc | published    | conda           | https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc
```

so, should I just try to reinstall pymc using one of these packages, and if so, is the command the following?:

```
 conda install -c https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc pymc
```

should I remove 1st the package previously installed? or the new installation will over-write(?). Or perhaps it is easy to fix those errors I found before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing gfortran. If you haven't first install [brew](http://brew.sh):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Follow the instructions and once brew is correctly set up just do:

```
brew install gfortran
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. A couple of questions. ruby is an installer, right? is it a built in tool in the mac, or should I install it 1st? and also, if I type the "brew install" command, will it place gfortran in the adequate directory. I am just wondering if there is a way to do this using anaconda, so I don't have "path-problems" later...just wondering, if not, I will manage.

Comment: I solve installing gfortran from here: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS and then using "pip install git+https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc@2.3"

Comment: @Javier, great!! just to answer your question, ruby is already installed, brew will place gfortran in the adequate directory.

Answer (score 2):

`gfortran` now seems to be part of `gcc`

*NOTE: the below takes a while, took me 80 minutes to install this on MacBook pro*
`brew install gcc`

BTW, the above also seems to be a required installation if you want to use `PyMC` and are *not* using the anaconda distribution

Answer (score 1):

Another way that should work (on Mac OS X) is to `conda install -c asmeurer pymc`. This will install the gcc package (which includes gfortran) from my Binstar channel along with pymc.